# Repeatedly getting 404 errors while trying to submit React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm working on a **forum** using Express/React and I'm having trouble submitting the data from the form to the database. For now I'm just trying to add topic titles to its own MongoDB collection but in the future I plan on adding more message content. I have no idea why it's not working. I have another similar form for registering account and it's working just fine. When I `console.log(title)` it shows the title so I know I'm getting the data but I'm stuck with getting that data to save to the database after debugging for several days. Again, what I'm trying to do is make a form and enter the title of a topic and save that data to a database so that users can enter a topic and (in the future) make their own posts inside the topic.

This is the error code I'm getting when I hit submit.

`POST http://localhost:3000/topic/create 404 (Not Found)`

Here is my `url` that the form is located under.

`http://localhost:3000/topic/create`

Here is my `server.js` route code.

`app.use("/topic", topicRoutes);`

I'm using `npm run dev` to run the server.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
    "client": "npm run dev --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Here's my forumApiSlice

```
const TOPIC_URL = "/topic";
export const forumApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    create: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${TOPIC_URL}/create`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Here is my form code.

```
const CreateTopic = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [create] = useCreateMutation(); // forumApiSlice

  const { userInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.auth); // to get the author of the topic

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await create({ title, author }).unwrap();
      dispatch({ ...res });
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(err.error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Create Topic</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group className="my-2" controlId="title">
          <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Title"
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="my-2" controlId="author">
          <Form.Label></Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={userInfo.name}
            onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type="submit" variant="primary" className="mt-3">
          Create Topic
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};
```

And here's my backend code.

```
router.post("/create", createTopic);

const createTopic = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { title, author } = req.body;

  const topicExists = await Topic.findOne({ title });

  if (topicExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Topic Already Exists!");
  }

  const topic = await Topic.create({
    title,
    author,
    postCount: 1,
  });

  if (topic) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: topic._id,
      title: topic.title,
      author: topic.author,
      postCount: topic.postCount,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid Topic Data");
  }
});
```

Comment: 404 means you are calling the wrong server url. Is the server running? Where is it running?

Comment: @Kokodoko I'm using `npm run dev` to run the server. i've added the code to the post just now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which port your backend server is running on? You can't run your frontend and backend code on the same port. Typically a node server runs on port 5000 so your api url should be **http://localhost:5000/topic/create**

Comment: My server is being run on port 5000 and my frontend is being run on port 3000. When I posted the url I meant that's the url I'm being redirected to when I go to create a topic.